# Count number of Vertices in VertexBuffer in XNA 3.1

Tags: xna, c#, vertex

Where in XNA 4.0 one can go:

```
 myVertexBuffer.VertexCount;
```

What is the best way to count the number of vertices in 3.1 for a dynamic buffer (i.e. where I do not know the number of elements that could be therein). I have come up with:

```
myVertexBuffer.SizeInBytes / VertexPositionNormalTexture.SizeInBytes
```

Where my vertices are VertexPositionNormalTexture's, but is this the best way? (it will be called often in Draw()).

Comment: That's (likely) the only way. Or, close enough. IIRC the vertex declaration type has a 'vertex stride' parameter that you should use rather than the size in bytes. If your vertex buffer is from a model, you should use the vertex declaration from the model, since it might have additional elements (meaning the stride is larger than VertexPositionNormalTexture.) Not an answer since I can't confirm anything; I don't have 3.1 installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Blecki's answer is correct, I also don't have 3.1 installed, but some quick googling with bing shows a few [examples](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/60962/374878.aspx).

```
foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes) 
        { 
            int numberVertices, numberIndices; 
            numberVertices = 
                mesh.VertexBuffer.SizeInBytes / mesh.MeshParts[0].VertexStride; 
            if (mesh.IndexBuffer.IndexElementSize == IndexElementSize.SixteenBits) 
                numberIndices = mesh.IndexBuffer.SizeInBytes / sizeof(short); 
            else 
                numberIndices = mesh.IndexBuffer.SizeInBytes / sizeof(int); 

            totalNumVertices += numberVertices; 
            totalNumFaces += numberIndices / 3; 
        }
```

Comment: "googling with bing" - Nice one!